# Positioning edges in a diagraph

Tags: graphviz, dot, graphing

I'm attempting to make a 2-4 tree in DOT. I've got the tree I need built, but I want to position the ends of the edges so that it more accurately reflects a 2-4 tree.

I've got the following graph

```
digraph g {
   node [shape = record,height=.1,label=" | "];
   n0 -> n1;
   n0 -> n2;
   n0 -> n3;
   n1 -> n4;
   n1 -> n5;
   n1 -> n6;
   n2 -> n7;
   n2 -> n8;
   n2 -> n9;
   n3 -> n10;
   n3 -> n11
   n3 -> n12;
}
```

Which renders to the following: 
[image: digraph image]

I want it so that  it would render more like the following (where the red represents the edge I would like):

[image: preferred edge endings]

Comment: Take a look at 'node ports' in the graphiz docs, you can give an edge attributes which describe where the edges should attach. http://web.mit.edu/spin_v4.2.5/share/graphviz/doc/html/info/attrs.html#k:portPos

Comment: Thanks for the help @pvg! Ports worked. I'll post my solution in a bit.